# Add Docker label if variable is true in an Ansible playbook

Tags: docker, ansible

I'm trying to set up an ansible entry where a docker label is added to a container only if a variable is true, and skip it if false.

An example, if `use_my_label_1: true`

```yaml
- docker_container:
    name: sleeper
    image: docker.io/alpine:latest
    command: sleep inf
    labels:
      my_label_1: "something"
      my_label_2: "something else"
```

else if `use_my_label_1: false`

```yaml
- docker_container:
    name: sleeper
    image: docker.io/alpine:latest
    command: sleep inf
    labels:
      my_label_2: "something else"
```

I searched online and I can only find examples of setting label values, or skipping tasks entirely, but not what I need. would one accomplish this?

Comment: Please read the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page,
and pay especial attention to the [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) section, then [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72953852/edit) and include your code

Comment: Also remember that Stack Overflow is for programming questions.  Questions about using automation tools like Ansible to deploy containers might be better asked on a sibling site like [devops.se].

Comment: Thank you @DavidMaze, I will keep it in mind

Comment: Thank you @mdaniel, I updated my question with a reproducible example in order to help possible future users who have the same issue as me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to use the [`omit`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#making-variables-optional) special value along with the [`ternary`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#defining-different-values-for-true-false-null-ternary) filter:

```
    - docker_container:
        name: sleeper
        image: docker.io/alpine:latest
        command: sleep inf
        labels:
          my_label_1: "{{ use_my_label_1|default(false)|ternary('something', omit) }}"
          my_label_2: "something else"
```

If `use_my_label_1` is `true`, this will apply both `my_label_1` and `my_label_2`. If `use_my_label_1` is `false` or undefined, it will only apply `my_label_2`.